# Setting blank = False for email field in django authentication

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using django built-in authentication and for that authetication system, we are given different fields like username, email, password etc.

`Username` by default is required and also not blank but for email it is not required (i.e, it is null) which makes it blank also.

Now for making it required, i added this code;

```
extra_kwags = {'email': {'required': True}}
```

I tried the same with `blank`;

```
extra_kwags = {'email': {'required': True, 'blank': False}}
```

But it gives error saying `blank` is not a valid keyword there.

So i want to know if there is a way to set `blank=False` for the email field in django.

Though i know a way which is by making the email_verification mandatory and making email the way to autheticate;

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email' 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
```

But i want to know if there is another way as i don't want it to make authentication_method.

Comment: `blank` is for a option for a *model* field, not for a *form field*. So `required` is sufficient.

Comment: As for required only, we can still pass empty strings. That is why i want to set blank to false so that empty string will return error

Comment: I think required makes null false not blank

Comment: no if you specify `blank=True` on the *model* field, you make the corresponding *form* field *not* required.

Comment: And i also checked it by first removing the required keyword and i was able to make the request even without the email but after setting required on it, though i have to mention the email in my request but i was able to pass empty string as the value

Comment: Maybe i have understood it wrong but what i want is i want empty string to return error

Comment: I don't want email field to take empty string as a valid value

Comment: And i am using it in DRF

Comment: @Irfanwani Please show your view and serializer. An empty string should normally raise some validation error. Also you could have simply edited instead of commenting 3 times in short succession...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option is named `allow_blank` in rest framework [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield)

So you can use this and validation should work

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class YourUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   ...

   class Meta:
       model = YourUserModel
       extra_kwargs = {'email': {'required': True, 'allow_blank': False}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what i was searching. I was missing 'allow_'